# Не понимаю действия с переменными в python

Tags: python

Только начал изучать питон, вот в чем проблема

[image: вот сама программа]

Допустим, я хочу, чтобы переменная a "запоминала" значение переменной b в определенном этапе программы. И чтобы я мог в любое время вызвать a  и получить значение [1,2,3]
Однако, питон выводит [1,2,3,4]
Почему так происходит, и как это исправить?

Comment: Замените изображение текстом.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы пишете `a = b`, то не создаете новый список `a`, но просто ссылаетесь на список `b`. В итоге получается, что обе переменные ссылаются на один и тот же список.
Чтобы получить 2 разных списка, создайте переменную `a`, содержащую копию списка `b`:

```
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> a = b[:]
>>> b.append(4)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```